# Send a request and re-render the page with the new data in EJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

I have different `name` data sent from server side by EJS, put in `<a></a>` tags:

```
<div>
     <% namesArr.forEach(name => { %>
         <a class="other-categories" data-doc="<%= name %>" id="<%= name %>">
            <%= name %>
         </a>
     <% }); %>
</div>
```

A chosen name would be used inside img.src to display image:

```
<div><img src="/imgs/<%=selectedName.replace(/\s/g,'%20')%>/<%=imgArr[i]%>"></div>
```

I hope when another `name` is clicked, the page somehow refreshes and re-renders with the specific `name` I click.

I don't know how to request something from client side to server side, I guess I would need new values such as `{newSelectedName, namesArr, imgArr}` for below code, since all values come from `res.render` by `Express.js` and database using Mongoose model:

```
Category.find()
.then(result => {
    #getNamesFunction
    #getImgArrFunction
    res.render('index', {selectedName, namesArr, imgArr})
})
.catch(err => console.log(err));
```

I was thinking to use `fetch()` and `GET` method to send a request again, maybe like this:

```
const otherCategories = document.querySelectorAll('.other-categories');
const endpoint = `/all-categories`;

otherCategories.forEach(category => {
    category.addEventListener('click', function(){
        fetch(endpoint, {
            method: 'GET'
        })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => #doSomeThing)
        .catch(err => console.log(err))
    })
})
```

I'm not even sure if this method makes sense, I feel like there is a way to get specific response by different request, so that it might be helpful in my situation.

Comment: How is your `routing` defined for this page on the express side? Can you just once again request for the page based on `name` value selected, where you pass the `name` value as `query string param`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**There are many ways, I am sharing one of them**

**1. routing**

You have to use two rout path one with param and one without param

```
req.get("/image",(req,res)=>{res.render("image", {name:"nameFromServerSide"})})


req.get("/image/:name",(req,res)=>{res.render("image", {name: req.params.name})})
```

**2.image.ejs**

you have to use `<a></a>` tag
on every name you have

```
<a href="/image/nameOfTheImage1"><button >nameOfTheImage1</button></a>
<a href="/image/nameOfTheImage2"><button >nameOfTheImage2</button></a>
```